# "orderer binary" command not working in docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I'm trying to launch my hyperledger fabric network using docker-compose which has all the "orderer and peer" configs in the environment section of the docker-compose file.

But When I launch the docker-compose file using "docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml up -d", I get this error as result :

**" cannot start service orderer.org.com: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "orderer": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown".**

knowing that I exported all the necessary environment variables such as "export the PATH=bin:$PATH and the FABRIC_CFG_PATH".

Moreover, I did not get the same error with the peer binary in the same docker-compose file

- **** :

**this is the configuration part of my orderer in the docker-compose file

orderer.supplychain.com:

```
container_name: orderer.org.supplychain.com
image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
labels:
  service: hyperledger-fabric
environment:
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=7050
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=INFO
  - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
  - FABRIC_CFG_PATH=/var/hyperledger/config
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
  #- ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=none
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_BOOTSTRAPFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer-genesis.block
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
  #- ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
  #- ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1
  #- ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
  - ORDERER_METRICS_PROVIDER=prometheus
  - ORDERER_OPERATIONS_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8443
working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderers
command: orderer //notworking
volumes:
  - ${PWD}/config/orderer:/var/hyperledger/config
  - ./artifacts-channels/supply-genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer-supply-genesis.block
  - ./crypto-material/organizations/ordererOrganizations/orderer.supplychain.com/orderers/orderer.supplychain.com/msp/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
  - ./crypto-material/organizations/ordererOrganizations/orderer.supplychain.com/orderers/orderer.supplychain.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
  - orderer.org.supplychain.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
ports:
  - 7050:7050
  - 8443:8443
networks:
  - supplychain**
```

---

this is the part of peers

**peer0.productionlaborg.supplychain.com:

```
container_name: peer0.productionlaborganisation.supplychain.com
image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
labels:
  service: hyperledger-fabric
environment:
  - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
  #- CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb1:5984
  - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=admin
  - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=adminpw
  - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.productionlaborg.supplychain.com
  - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.productionlaborg.supplychain.com:7051
  - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
  - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.productionlaborg.supplychain.com:7052
  - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.productionlaborg.supplychain.com:8051
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.productionlaborg.supplychain.com::7051
  - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=ProductionLabOrg
  - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
  - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
  - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
volumes: 
  - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
  - ./crypto-material/organizations/peerOrganizations/productionlaborg.supplychain.com/peers/peer0.productionlaborg.supplychain.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
  - ./crypto-material/organizations/peerOrganizations/productionlaborg.supplychain.com/peers/peer0.productionlaborg.supplychain.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
  - peer0.productionlaborg.supplychain.com:/var/hyperledger/production
working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peers
command: peer node start
depends_on:
  #- couchdb1
  - orderer.org.supplychain.com
ports: 
  - 7051:7051
networks: 
  - supplychain**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the orderer image to run the orderer container, and update your container image to `hyperledger/fabric-orderer:2.4`.
Your orderer container definition should look like this

```
container_name: orderer.org.supplychain.com
image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:2.4
labels:
  service: hyperledger-fabric
environment:
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=7050
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=INFO
  - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
  - FABRIC_CFG_PATH=/var/hyperledger/config
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
  #- ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=none
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_BOOTSTRAPFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer-genesis.block
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
  #- ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
  #- ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1
  #- ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
  - ORDERER_METRICS_PROVIDER=prometheus
  - ORDERER_OPERATIONS_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8443
working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderers
command: orderer //notworking
volumes:
  - ${PWD}/config/orderer:/var/hyperledger/config
  - ./artifacts-channels/supply-genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer-supply-genesis.block
  - ./crypto-material/organizations/ordererOrganizations/orderer.supplychain.com/orderers/orderer.supplychain.com/msp/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
  - ./crypto-material/organizations/ordererOrganizations/orderer.supplychain.com/orderers/orderer.supplychain.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
  - orderer.org.supplychain.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
ports:
  - 7050:7050
  - 8443:8443
networks:
  - supplychain**
```

Answer (score 0):

So the first few lines, specifically

```
container_name: orderer.org.supplychain.com
image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
```

you are using the wrong image if you want to launch the orderer, it should be `fabric-orderer`